# How to assert gRPC error codes client side in Go

Tags: go, grpc

Given the following gRPC server side code:

```
import (
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
    ....
)

....

func (s *Router) Assign(ctx context.Context, req *api.Request(*api.Response, error) {

    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.PermissionDenied,
}

....
```

What is the recommended technique for asserting client side that the error is of code = `codes.PermissionDenied` ?

Comment: To clarify your question are you asking how can the client would know that the error code is `codes.PermissionDenied`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let's say your server returns `codes.PermissionDenined` like this

```
...
return nil, status.Error(codes.PermissionDenied, "PERMISSION_DENIED_TEXT")
```

If your client is Golang as well can also use the `status` library function `FromError` to parse the error. I use a switch to determine the error code returned like so

```
// client
    assignvar, err := s.MyFunctionCall(ctx, ...)
    if err != nil {
        if e, ok := status.FromError(err); ok {
            switch e.Code() {
            case codes.PermissionDenied:
                fmt.Println(e.Message()) // this will print PERMISSION_DENIED_TEST
            case codes.Internal:
                fmt.Println("Has Internal Error")
            case codes.Aborted:
                fmt.Println("gRPC Aborted the call")
            default:
                fmt.Println(e.Code(), e.Message())
            }
        }
        else {
            fmt.Printf("not able to parse error returned %v", err)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`status.Code`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.51.0/status#Code), to directly check the error code without the need to get a `Status` value first. For example:

```golang
if err != nil {
    switch status.Code(err) {
    case codes.NotFound:
        // handle not found

    case codes.FailedPrecondition:
        // handle failed precondition

    default:
        // handle other status codes
    }
}
```